# text processing

Tags: text-processing, text

I have two files.

file A :

```
       Chr1     Cufflinks     exon    2903   3268   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.1.2"; tss_id "TSS1";

       Chr1     Cufflinks     exon    3354   3616   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "2"; oId "CUFF.1.2"; tss_id "TSS1";

       Chr1     Cufflinks     exon    4357   4455   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000761"; exon_number "3"; oId "CUFF.1.2"; tss_id "TSS1";
```

file B;

```
TCONS_00000066
TCONS_00000600
TCONS_00000761
TCONS_00000762
TCONS_00000773
```

I want to match the B file to and print where ever match is there. In this case the id in file A is in 12th column.

the output should be like

```
    Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    4357    4455    .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000761"; exon_number "3"; oId "CUFF.1.2"; tss_id "TSS1";
```

the whole line from file A should be in file C

I tried awk commands but failed.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$12];next}; !($12 in a)' B A >C
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -fB A
```

will do what you're looking for; the `-f`option specifies a file from which patterns are loaded, one pattern per line. Any line in `A` which matches a pattern in `B` will be output.